# Can't send outgoing emails

Tags: email, postfix

I'm having issues sending emails from my localhost domain to outbound email servers (gmail, yahoo, etc). I can send emails inbound but when I try to send an email test to my gmail account it doesn't work.  Is it possible to send outbound emails with `postfix`, it's been very frustrating, I've been trying it during 2 days, I would appreciate some help.
This is my `main.cf` file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un$
myhostname = Server
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.mydomainlocalhost.com, Server, localhost.localdomain, localhost, domain.c$
#relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
myhostname = Server
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.mydomainlocalhost.com, Server, localhost.localdomain, localhost, domain.c$
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `mail.cf` your mail server user `dovecot`, `ssl`, `private cert` ...

Maybe is good solution to start from beginning with manual you have or with new.

I don't known what you wish/need.

For the first aid try to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

and fallow `wizard`

```
1) Choose 'Internet with smarthost' (recommended) to use another mail server for relaying mail 

2) Enter system mail name (mail.your_domain.com)

3) Enter SMTP relay host (your_isp_smtp_server.com)

4) Root and postmaster mail recipient (user@domail.com)

5) Other destinations to accept mail for (mail.your_domain.com, localhost.foo.tld, localhost)

6) Force synchronous updates on mail queue (No)

7) Local networks (127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128)

9) Mailbox size limit (bytes) (0)

10) Local address extension character (+)

11) Internet protocols to use (ipv4 is the safe choice)
```

Try.